# PasswordBox.SecurePassword not available on WinRT Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime

I'm developing a Windows Store app for Windows 8.1, C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I'm trying to use [PasswordBox.SecurePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it seems it is not available. I have changed framework version to 4.5, I have tried with a WPF test project with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and it is not available.

I have tried to add `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly to my Windows 8.1 Store app but I can't.

I'm trying to do this:

```
{
    PasswordBox pass = new PasswordBox();
    pass.SecurePassword // I'm checking if it is available
}
```

To check if `SecurePassword` exists, but `SecurePassword` is not available on Windows Store Apps.

Is `SecurePassword` available on Windows Store Apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid of saying that Windows Store Application cannot use SecureString
You should use Windows.Security.Credentials's method and object

10/07 Night(Japan Time) rewrote
I think you hope to do like log in work, don't do?
In case "Windows.Security.Credentials namespace" is a simple solution.

Please, look at above code

cs file

```
//MainPage.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Security.Credentials;

namespace App1
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        //Initialize Credential data
        try
        {
            var alldata = vault.FindAllByResource("My List");
            foreach (PasswordCredential data in alldata)
            {
                vault.Remove(data);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Certificate for Input data
        PasswordCredential credential = null;
        try
        {
            credential = vault.Retrieve("My List", Username.Text);

            if(credential.Password==password.Password)             
            {
                Status.Text = "Status : Succeed in Certificating";
            }
            else
            {
                Status.Text = "Status : Failed to Certification";
            }
        }
        catch { Status.Text = "Status : Failed to Certification"; }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Registar on Input data
        try
        {
            vault.Add(new PasswordCredential("My List", Username.Text, password.Password));
            Status.Text = "Status : Succeed in Registering";
        }
        catch
        {
            Status.Text = "Status : Failed to Register";
        }
    }
}
}
```

xaml file

```
<Page>

    <!-- MainPage.xaml -->
    <Grid>
        <PasswordBox Name="password"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="531,197,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="464" FontSize="52"/>
        <TextBox Name="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="531,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="464" FontSize="52"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="10,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="UserName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505" FontSize="80"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="10,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PassWord" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505" FontSize="80"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="10,327,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Status " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1329" FontSize="60"/>

        <Button Content="Certification" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" Margin="1006,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="336" Click="Button_Click" FontSize="52"/>

        <Button Content="Registration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" Margin="1006,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="336" Click="Button_Click_1" FontSize="52"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

1.Make a "PasswordVault" instance

-Registar a data
2a.Use PasswordVault.Add Method with PasswordCredential instance
PasswordCredential Instance need 3 Parameters
1st Parameter : Resource Name (any value) type string
2nd Parameter : UserName type string
3rd Parameter : Password type string

-Certificate a data
2b.Use PasswordVault.Retribe Method with 2paraeters
1st Parameter : Resource Name (you must use the same name that you used on Registration)
2nd Parameter : UserName
return PasswordCredential value
You can get Password and UserName from PasswordCredential value

for example

```
//data is a PasswordCredential value

//get Username
string username = data.UserName;
//get Password
string password = data.Password
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand it. Is there a XAML control called Windows.Security.Credentials?

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, but I'm not english or american and I don't understand the meaning of `log` in this sentence: `I think you hope to do like log in work, don't do?` Thanks.

Comment: Also I'm not a native speaker of English. I'm a Japanese. In Japan, certification task is often called "log in task". I'm sorry for making you misleading